# Integrate Vim and Git on Windows

Tags: windows, git, vim

I've been using gVim for a while now on my Windows box, and I love it. I'm not using Cygwin, and I'd rather not install it. I'm using the msysgit version of Git for Windows.

I'm looking to integrate Git into gVim, so that I don't have to constantly open msysgit and navigate to the correct directory. I feel that integrating the most important commands would really speed up/enhance my code development.

Is there a Vim plugin that would that will do this for me?

I finally just reinstalled Git For Windows a few times until I got the settings I want. I installed Git using the "Run Git and included Unix tools from the Windows Command Prompt." That seems to take care of getting the !git commands to mostly work from within Vim. This old blog post walked me through a few gotchas: http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/05/06/git-ssh-putty-github-unfuddle-the-kitchen-sink.aspx

Comment: I am using git bash, but it's so inefficient to open directories in cmd, explorer, vim, and git bash. Msysgit has a linuxy version of paths, C:\directory\ becomes /c/directory/. It's really annoying to switch back and forth

Comment: @Gitninja It is possible to use `C:/directory` in vim and some other windows commands, though none of them including vim will accept `/c/directory`. Try to get and use cygwin version of vim, it should be able to launch git or try to set 'shell' to cygwin bash (unsure whether it will work or whether it will respect current directory of non-cygwin process, thus first option should be the most likely to work).

Comment: I was hoping to avoid installing cygwin, since I didn't want to bloat my laptop anymore, but I guess I should really consider it. Thanks!!

Comment: @ZyX - I was able to reinstall Git as described in my edit above, and now I've got git working on the regular commandline without Cygwin. Thanks for advice though!

Comment: @Gitninja I was pretty sure msysgit already included cygwin, but it appears it does not: “Consequently, MSys ships with a POSIX layer (based on an old version of Cygwin) that is only used by the Bash and Perl, but not by anything compiled within that environment.” (from README in [msysgit repository](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit)).

Comment: The link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many Git frontends I know about: [Fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) and [VCSCommand](http://repo.or.cz/w/vcscommand.git) were already mentioned, and there are also [vim-addon-git](https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-git) (Git only), [vcsi](https://github.com/kana/vim-vcsi/blob/master/doc/vcsi.txt) (multi-backend), [scmfrontend](https://bitbucket.org/ns9tks/vim-scmfrontend) (multi-backend), mine [aurum](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/aurum) (multi-backend, but I use almost only Mercurial thus others are not that well tested).

From what I know, Fugitive and aurum are the most feature-rich (the main thing I do not have are operations with Git index done by Fugitive), VCSCommand is also good (it is the oldest one and is very popular, thus having lots of bugs fixed), others may have minor advantages, but AFAIK everything what is implemented by one of them is also implemented by fugitive or aurum (of course, I mean only things concerning Git).

And yes, I also know nothing about how well any of these integrate with msysgit. Mine should work as far as `system('git')` works, but under [Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) (Wine) only Mercurial was tested.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out fugitive. I'm definitely going to add that to Vimg!

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) (Git-only) or [VCSCommand](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=90) (multi-backend) but I don't know how well they integrate with `msysgit`.

It's probably a dumb question but: doesn't `:!git commit<CR>` work?

Comment: If `!git commit` does not work it is much likely than none of other plugins will work, especially out-of-the-box.

Comment: Yes, that was the meaning of my question.

Comment: unfortunately, !git commands don't work, and git doesn't work from the regular commandline.

Comment: @ZyX, you're were on to something here. Once I reinstall Git to be added to the path, those commands all work. I do find it easier to add/commit/push/pull/checkout the current file in vim using your suggestion now. +1